# Host multiple Angular 2 applications in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angular

We are re-writing a large application and decided we want to use Angular 2.  Because of the size of the application, we want to break it down into sub-applications for each section.  Our goal is to use MVC routing at the project level to get to each of the sub-applications.  The index page for each sub-app would deliver the Angular application to the browser and Angular would take over the routing within that sub-app.  Our project level (MVC) navigation menu will be across the top of the application window and the navigation for each section (handled by Angular) will be a vertical navbar down the left.  My question is, how should we structure the folders in the Solution to best achieve sanity as the project grows?

Comment: are you planing to share "common components" within the diffrent sub apps?

Comment: Yes, I think it's likely that some of the services will be shared across components.

Comment: and you are gonna use Typescript?

Comment: https://johnpapa.net/angular-2-styles/

Comment: Yes, we're interested in using Typescript.

Comment: then you also need to copy the structure to another one when you transpile the .ts files

Comment: startup template for asp.net core with gulp scripts and structure https://github.com/Novatrox/aspnetcore-angular2-gulp-starter/tree/master/src/AngularGulpQuickstart

Comment: Follow up: We started down the path of using lazy loaded modules instead breaking the app into multiple Angular applications.  That was working well but management wanted us to go in a different technical direction and sadly we had to pull the plug on Angular.  ...someday...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be similar to the normal project except you can have Apps folder instead of one App folder, assuming that you have separation between your apps in functionality, so the structure can be like this:

Apps

-+- App1

-+- App2

-+- App3

-+- Shared

The shared fodler can have some common features such as services or custom components

Comment: Would the Apps folder sit in the root of the MVC project?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the root of the MVC project, some people put it under Scripts folder when you have it inside an MVC project

Comment: By doing this. Will you a get all javascript together in one file: app1 + app2 + app3? Or are you able to produce a set of javascript files for each app? If so how do you produce these output files?

Comment: @ManuelValle You can either group them all in one file using webpack, or find a way to group the files in each app into separate bundle and reference it only for its corresponding app since I believe there will be a full refresh when the user moves from one App to the other

Comment: Thanks, yes, I found webpack and I was able to configure a hybrid solution.